# how to identify a column in mysql when I have 2 with same name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this PHP code to get my sql query which joins 2 tables ... both table have the same "size" field, but the results is not the same in both... code:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_product.product_id =
cart.product_id WHERE .......) or die(mysql_error());
```

The result of this query shows me

Cart_id, member_id, product_id, size, .... and a second  size

1 of the size comes the cart table and 1 from the product table..

then I try to retrieve my data

```
while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array( $data))
{ 
    $size=  $data2['size'];
```

But I get the second size in my result and I need the first one.. I need the cart.size ...  how can I do this ?

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Either use aliase or specify the table,`cart.size`,`tbl_product.size`

Comment: A `print_r($data2)` will show you all fields. Then, you can access the different sizes by adding the table name in front of your field : `tbl_product.size`

Comment: (I find PDO impossible to learn - must be my age)

Answer (score 1):

Name the columns explicitly in your SELECT statement, and assign ALIASes to the columns with identical names:

```
SELECT cart.id_col, cart.size AS CartSize, ttbl_product.size AS ProductSize 
  FROM cart INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_product.product_id = cart.product_id 
  WHERE .......
```

then extract the value for ProductSize from the results.

If you don't need the cart size, you can eliminate it from the list of columns return and leave out the ALIAS, as you'll only have a single Size column in the results:

```
SELECT cart.id_col, ttbl_product.size  
  FROM cart INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_product.product_id = cart.product_id 
  WHERE .......
```

In general, it's a good idea to explicitly name the columns you want in your SELECT statement as it makes it clearer what you're getting back, it will fail sooner if you are trying to get a column that's not there (when the SELECT executes, not when you try to retrieve the column value from the result set), and can lead to better performance if you're only interested in a small-ish subset of the available columns.

Answer (score 1):

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is
>   used as the expression's column name [...]

This is a basic feature of the SELECT statement in SQL. Please consult the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL aliases. For examle:

```
SELECT a.a AS aa, b.a AS ba FROM tbl1 AS a, tbl2 AS b
```

Answer (score 0):

Change SELECT * to SELECT [fields] where you manually specify which fields you need. If you only need one then there's nothing left to do. If you need both then you can use an alias for the fields like this:

```
SELECT p.size AS product_size, c.size AS cart_size FROM ...
```

Then they will be available in your array as keys product_size and cart_size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT cart.size as cartsize, tbl_product.size as productsize, ...
FROM cart INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_product.product_id = cart.product_id
WHERE ...) or die(mysql_error());
```

But if you don't work on some legacy code you don't want to rewrite completely use PDO instead, like suggested in first the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Several comments to begin with:

1. I suggest to move away from `mysql_*` as soon as you can
2. Try not to use the `*` operator in your select statements

As for your question, use an alias for the two columns, I also like to give my tables a simpler alias (makes the query more concise):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.size AS cart_size, t2.size AS product_size FROM cart t1
INNER JOIN tbl_product t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Hope this helps.